# How can I map a function on dataFrame column values which returns a dataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark DataFrame, df1, which contains several columns, one of them is with IDs of patients. I want to take this column and perform a function that sends http request for information regarding every ID, say medical test. This information is then parsed from json and returned by the function as DataFrame of multiple tests. I want to do this for all the IDs so that I have a second DataFrame, df2, with all medical tests information for the IDs in df1.

I tried the following code, which I think is not optimal especially for large number of patients. My problem is that I cannot handle the results in the form of Array[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame]. Note this is a sample code, in real life I might have 100 tests for one ID and only 3 for another.

```
import scala.util.Random._

val df1 = Seq(
  ("9031x", 32),
  ("1102z", 12),
  ("3048o", 54)
).toDF("ID", "age")

// a function that takes the string and returns a DataFrame
def getPatientInfo(ID: String): org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = {
  val r = scala.util.Random
  val df2 = Seq(
      ("test1", r.nextInt(100), r.nextInt(40)+1980, r.nextString(4)),
      ("test2", r.nextInt(100), r.nextInt(40)+1980, r.nextString(3)),
      ("test3", r.nextInt(100), r.nextInt(40)+1980, r.nextString(5))
      ).toDF("testName", "year", "result", "Notes") 
  df2
}
// convert the ID to Array[String]
val ID = df1.collect().map(row => row.getString(0))

// apply the function foreach ID
val medicalRecords = for (i <- ID) yield {getPatientInfo(i)}
```

Are there any other optimal approaches?

Comment: I would suggest you to define a udf function to do the fetching part and return an array for information. then explode the array .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR;**

It is not possible `DataFrame.map` (or equivalent method) cannot use `SparkSession` or distributed data structures.

If you want make it work, use your favorite JSON parser instead and redefine `getPatient` as either:

```
def getPatientInfo(ID: String): Seq[Row]
```

or

```
def getPatientInfo(ID: String): T
```

where `T` is a `case` class and replace:

```
df1.flatMap(row => getPatientInfo(row.getString(0)))
```

(adding `Encoder` if necessary).